# Devise Rspec sign in test with rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

In my authentication spec i have

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Authentication" do

    subject { page }

    describe "Signup page" do
        before { visit new_user_registration_path }

        let(:submit) { "Create my account" }

        describe "with invalid information" do
          it "should not create a user" do
            expect { click_button submit }.not_to change(User, :count)
          end

          describe "after submission" do
            before { click_button submit }

            it { should have_content('Sign up') }
            it { should have_content('error') }
          end
        end

        describe "with valid information" do
          before do
            fill_in "First name",   with: "Example"
            fill_in "Last name",    with: "Lastname"
            fill_in "Username",     with: "exampleguy"
            fill_in "Email",        with: "user@example.com"
            fill_in "Password",     with: "foobar1234"
          end

          it "should create a user" do
            expect { click_button submit }.to change(User, :count).by(1)
          end

          #describe "after saving the user" do
            #before { click_button submit }
            #let(:user) { User.find_by(email: 'user@example.com') }

            #it { should have_title(user.first_name) }
            #it { should have_selector('div.flash_success', text: 'Welcome') }
         # end
        end

        it { should have_content('Sign up') }
    end


    describe "Signin page" do 

        before { visit new_user_session_path }

        describe "with invalid information" do
            before { click_button "Sign in" }

            it { should have_content('Sign in') }
            it { should have_selector('div.flash_alert', text: "Invalid") }

        end

        describe "with valid information" do
            let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
            before do 
                fill_in "Email",    with: user.email
                fill_in "Password", with: user.password
                click_button "Sign in"
            end

            it { should_not have_selector('a', text: 'Sign up')}
            it { should_not have_selector('a', text: 'Sign in')}
            it { should have_selector('a', text: 'Profile') }
            it { should have_selector('a', text: 'Sign Out') }
            it { should have_selector('div.flash_notice', text: "Signed in successfully.") }

        end

        it { should have_content('Sign in') }
    end
end
```

And in factories.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    first_name  "Example"
    last_name   "User"
    username    "exampleuser"
    email       "user@example.com"
    password    "foobar1234"
  end
end
```

Every test is working apart from the sign in -with valid information set of tests. I have no clue as to why, and its working normally in the browser. Has anyone come across a problem like this?

Comment: Can you add the lines that are failing?

Comment: Yeah those in Signin page -> with valid information e.g. it { should_not have_selector('a', text: 'Sign up')} and the rest in that test group.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're using the devise confirmable module, you have to add user.confirm! to your sign in method.
Put this in support/utilities.rb

```
def sign_in(user)
   user.confirm!
   visit new_user_session_path
   fill_in "Email",    with: user.email
   fill_in "Password", with: user.password
   click_button "Sign in"
end
```

In your describe block "with valid information" change this

```
before do 
   fill_in "Email",    with: user.email
   fill_in "Password", with: user.password
   click_button "Sign in"
end
```

to this.

```
before { sign_in(user) }
```

Comment: Rather than `support/utilities.rb`, should it not be `spec/support/utilities.rb`?

Comment: Yh, you get what i am trying to say.